# How do I use GNU split's "filter" option with GNU parallel?

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

I am trying to split a number of huge gz file into N-line compressed gzipped chunks.

To demonstrate, let us consider the following:

```
seq 100 | gzip > big_file0.gz
```

I can split this into multiple 10-line compressed files as follows:

```
zcat big_file0.gz | split -l 10 --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' - big_file0.
```

Let us assume we have a number of big files `big_file0.gz`, `big_file1.gz` ...

I would now like to split each of these files using GNU parallel. Here's the command I come up with:

```
parallel "zcat {} | split -l 10 --filter='gzip > $FILE.gz' - {.}." ::: big_file0.gz big_file1.gz
```

However, the shell substitution for `$FILE` does not work as expected. `$FILE` is replaced with an empty string, so all the output is written to a file called `.gz`.

How can I get the `$FILE` substitution to work as expected in GNU parallel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shell expansion of variables is converting `$FILE` to an empty string.  You need to put a backslash in front of `$FILE` to prevent the shell from doing the expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Today you would use GNU Parallel's `--pipe` option:

```
parallel --seqreplace // "zcat {} | parallel --pipe -N 10 gzip '>{.}.{#}.gz'" ::: big_file0.gz big_file1.gz
```

If you are OK with appending `big_file0.gz big_file1.gz` it is even simpler:

```
zcat big_file0.gz big_file1.gz | parallel --pipe -N 10 gzip '>{#}.gz'
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "appending" here.